# Geant4, example B1 build error: no rule to make target

Tags: makefile, cmake, target

I'm trying to compile the B1 example for Geant4-10.0.1. This link provides instructions
http://geant4.web.cern.ch/geant4/UserDocumentation/UsersGuides/InstallationGuide/html/ch03s02.html

I have two separate dir: B1 and B1-build. Everything is normal up until

$ make -jN

I get the following error

```
$ make -j4
Scanning dependencies of target exampleB1
[ 12%] [ 37%] [ 37%] [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/exampleB1.dir/src/B1Run.cc.o
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/exampleB1.dir/src/B1PrimaryGeneratorAction.cc.o
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/exampleB1.dir/exampleB1.cc.o
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/exampleB1.dir/src/B1EventAction.cc.o
[ 62%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/exampleB1.dir/src/B1RunAction.cc.o
[ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/exampleB1.dir/src/B1DetectorConstruction.cc.o
[ 87%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/exampleB1.dir/src/B1ActionInitialization.cc.o
[100%] make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib64/libexpat.so', needed by 'exampleB1'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/exampleB1.dir/src/B1SteppingAction.cc.o
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:94: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/exampleB1.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/exampleB1.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:116: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

--Edit--

After trying

$ make VERBOSE=1

it ended with a similar error message:

```
.
.
.
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/exampleB1.dir/src/B1SteppingAction.cc.o
/usr/bin/c++   -DG4UI_USE -DG4UI_USE_TCSH -DG4VERBOSE -DG4VIS_USE -DG4_STORE_TRAJECTORY -W -Wall -pedantic -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-long-long -Wwrite-strings -Wpointer-arith -Woverloaded-virtual -Wno-variadic-macros -Wshadow -pipe -std=c++98 -I/usr/local/geant4.10.00.p01-install/include/Geant4 -I/1/home/walterms/geant4builds/B1/include    -o CMakeFiles/exampleB1.dir/src/B1SteppingAction.cc.o -c /1/home/walterms/geant4builds/B1/src/B1SteppingAction.cc
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib64/libexpat.so', needed by 'exampleB1'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/1/home/walterms/geant4builds/B1-build'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:94: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/exampleB1.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/exampleB1.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/1/home/walterms/geant4builds/B1-build'
Makefile:116: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Still lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to build the B1 example you refer to after installing the library.

I extracted geant4.10.00.p01.tar.gz.

then

```
mkdir build && cd build && \
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../geant4-install ../geant4.10.00.p01 && \
make -j8 && make install
```

Then I executed

```
source ./geant4.sh
```

in geant4-install/bin.

I build the B1 sample as follows:

```
cd geant4.10.00.p01/examples/basic/B1 && \
mkdir build && cd build && cmake ../ && make
```

This built *and* linked the example.

Again .. do you have libexpat installed? /usr/lib64/libexpat.so points to a valid shared library?

Comment: I'm not sure how to check where libexpat.so points. As well, I have two files: libexpat.so.1 and libexpat.so.1.6.0. I'm not sure if that changes things or not.
To install libexpat, would i 

$ sudo get-apt install libexpat

Comment: sudo apt-get install libexpat-dev should install both the library and header files. "ls -la /path/to/library" should show you where it points to. See if that gives any clues.

Comment: The root user is inaccessible to me unfortunately. It looks like libexpat isn't pointing to anything:

"$ ls -la /usr/lib64/libexpat.so.1" gives
"lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 May 23 13:29 /usr/lib64/libexpat.so.1 -> libexpat.so.1.6.0*"
 And then "$ ls -la /usr/lib64/libexpat.so.1.6.0" gives
"-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 173032 Oct 19  2013 /usr/lib64/libexpat.so.1.6.0*"

Comment: I think that this is OK. A symbolic link pointing to a file. For some reason cmake generates an invalid make rule - invalid since it tries to generate a symbolic lib which is installed system-wide.. At least you know that the cmake files work with ubuntu/cmake version 2.8.12.2.

Comment: !!!!Ok I got the root user to install the new expat and everything's fine....for now. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

It means you the expat library is not found. If your are developing something using the expat then you have to install dev version of expat library:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libexpat1-dev
```

If you are using the expat library not for development then install using below command:

```
sudo apt-get install -y expat
```